# Adding color to html element based on string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## Condition for coloring:-

```
Operators - > = *                      // "brown color"
Number =>                             //red color
string(inside double/single quotes) => green color 
string(without double/single quotes) => black color
```

[image]

So, if string is as it is in pic, how to return color to the string based on above mentioned condition.

The user entered the below text inside a conteneditable div.

```
<div contentEditable="true"  onInput={(e) => this.inputValue(e)}></div>

inputValue(e){ console.log(event.target.value) }
```

Comment: Are you looking to perform syntax highlighting?

Comment: To be clear, this is quite a massive task. It involves parsing the string into its elements, wrapping the individual parts in spans to be able to color them, and applying it as innerHTML to the div.

Comment: Yes, its kind of syntax highlighting. Basically user is entering a formula as string and we need to highlight. Can you please guide to solve the problem.

Comment: There are libraries out there that already do that for you, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel. What language are you trying to syntax highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use JS lib for that.

You can also provide custom css [Doc](https://highlightjs.org/usage/)

```js
const html = hljs.highlightAuto('isNaN("Name")/2 * if(5>3, "true","false") === Date').value;

document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = html;


console.log(html);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.0.1/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.0.1/highlight.min.js"></script>

<div id="code"></div>
```

If you inspect this code result you will see some common classes like built_in, string, number etc. you can override those classes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still I am confused about how to provide custom color based on above conditions.

Comment: You can check this doc, https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#configure.

If you inspect this code result you will see some common classes like built_in, string, number you can override those classes.